# How to access a csv without downloading it in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, dictionary, javascript-objects

I'm trying to access [this csv](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/offensive-security/exploitdb/master/files_exploits.csv) and convert it to a list of dictionaries via a javascript program. Is there any way I can get it without downloading it to my local machine?

I know python has pandas.read_csv('<enter_link_here>'), so I was wondering if there was something similar in javascript.

Comment: What do you mean with "without downloading it"? Not storing it on your local file system or not fetching it from a server into memory?

Comment: @A_A Yes, I don't want to store it on my local file system. I just want to access it from the given link.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is such a tool in the JavaScript world - https://www.papaparse.com/docs#remote-files